# Azure EventHub: checkpoint best practices in C# EventProcessorClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.consumer.eventhubconsumerclient.readeventsasync?view=azure-dotnet) `EventProcessorClient` is recommended way to consume eventhub streams:

> **EventProcessorClient** should be used for reading events from all partitions in a production scenario, as it offers a much more robust experience with higher throughput.

`EventProcessorClient` allows to update consumer's offset only inside message handler i.e. for each message, something like:

```
var eventProcessorClient = new EventProcessorClient(...);
eventProcessorClient.ProcessEventAsync += ProcessEventHandler;
eventProcessorClient.StartProcessingAsync(stoppingToken);

...

static async Task ProcessEventHandler(ProcessEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received event: {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Data.Body.ToArray()));
    await eventArgs.UpdateCheckpointAsync(eventArgs.CancellationToken);
}
```

At the same time in [documentation for eventhub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-processor-balance-partition-load#checkpointing):

> Updating after each successfully processed event can have performance and cost implications as it triggers a write operation to the underlying checkpoint store. Also, checkpointing every single event is indicative of a queued messaging pattern for which a Service Bus queue might be a better option than an event hub. The idea behind Event Hubs is that you get "at least once" delivery at great scale.

How to update partition checkpoint in efficient way? Should I use kafka client instead of `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkpointing after each message is not a good idea.  I'd recommend you checkpoint after each batch of messages that you have processed, for instance after each 50 messages (I think the number depends on how many messages you're processing etc...)

Next to that, you should think on how you deal with messages that are processed twice.  It could happend for instance that your `EventProcessorClient` crashes, which means that he'll restart reading from EventHub on the last checkpointed position.  In that case, you'll read some messages that you might have processed already.  So in that case, you'll need to think of a mechanism that can handle that.

Comment: Do you mean that I should support some `Interlocked.Increment(ref msgCounter)` inside `ProcessEventHandler` and call `UpdateCheckpointAsync` for every 50th message?

Comment: Something like that yes; (50th message was just an example, the size of the 'batch' will be dependent on your use case)

Comment: Checkpoints are written [per consumer group and partition ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-processor-balance-partition-load#checkpointing). If you would use a message counter per consumer group, then you would write a checkpoint just for the partition of the 50th message. Isn't it better to use a counter per consumer group and partition ID?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a timer with diff checking is better than number count.

With number count, if there isn't any new event for a long time, you will never update the checkpoint.

```cs
public class EventListener
    {
        private readonly Timer updateCheckpointTimer;
        private ProcessEventArgs? lastEventArgs;

        public EventListener(...)
        {
            ...
            this.updateCheckpointTimer = new Timer(this.UpdateCheckpoint, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
        }

        public async Task ProcessEventAsync(ProcessEventArgs args)
        {
            // business logic
            ...

            this.lastEventArgs = args;
        }

        private async void UpdateCheckpoint(object state)
        {
            if (this.lastEventArgs is ProcessEventArgs args)
            {
                await args.UpdateCheckpointAsync(args.CancellationToken);
                this.lastEventArgs = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EventProcessorClient can be configured to emit an empty event periodically during quiet periods.  I find this feature combined with the simple counter to be effective and easy to understand. I would count per partition as @dotarj mentioned above.

Comment: Hey @Kevin could you tell how to make EventProcessorClient emit events at intervals?

Comment: @Narayana You can pass EventProcessorClientOptions to the EventProcessorClient's constructor. One of the properties of the options is MaximumWaitTime.  It's the maximum amount of time to wait for an event before emitting an empty event. In your handler, the ProcessEventArgs.HasEvent will be false.

Comment: @Narayana Also, UpdateCheckpointAsync will error for the empty arg. You could hold onto the last real arg like the sample above, or just don't worry about it and update checkpoint on the next real event after a bunch of empty ones.  You should be assuming events are "at least once" anyways so keeping your offset closely sync'ed may not be necessary.  I'm okay with the risk of a few messages being replayed if a processor stops abruptly.